# Typescript stuck when compiling file that use immutable.js Map typing

Tags: typescript, angular, immutable.js

I have angular2 app and i'm using `immutable.js`. When i use user `Map` function from `immutable` typescript compiler gets stuck. When i don't import the typing from `immutable.js` it works fine but i get errors for every function that i use from `immutable.js.

```
import {Map} from 'immutable';
```

this is the line that blocks typescript.

Comment: Blocks? What's the actual error message?

Comment: No error msg. Simply typescript is stuck and i have to use `ctrl + c` to shut it down

Comment: @VadimMacagon if i remove the typings from `tsd.d.ts` the compiler doesn't block but i get syntax errors for every function/class that i use from `immutable.js`

Answer (score 3):

The `Map` from immutable.js may conflict with TypeScript's internal `Map`. To resolve the collision, you can try something like `import {Map} as MyMap from 'immutable'` and use `MyMap` in your code.

You could also use `import * as Immutable from 'immutable'` and access features in the `Immutable` namespace.

Comment: i tried it like this `import {Map as MyMap}  from 'immutable'` and its not working. Also crashes with using namespace. It is working when i import function that isn't `Map`

Comment: Don't put `as MyMap` in the curly braces. What happens if you use `import * as Immutable from 'immutable'` and access `Immutable.Map`?

Comment: If i don't put `as MyMap` in the curly braces i get syntax error if i use `import * as Immutable from 'immutable'` typescript compiler still blocks

Comment: I just went to the immutable.js page (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) and they provide a TypeScript example that imports code with `import Immutable = require('immutable');` and then accesses `Immutable.Map`. Does this work for you?

Comment: Still fails to run :(

Comment: Same issue, does not help me either

Comment: @Lex It's working for me.  If you still have the problem with the latest stable TypeScript (3.0.1), then maybe you could try building TypeScript from source (clone https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript, `npm install`, `jake local`) and running it under the debugger (`node --inspect-brk built/local/tsc.js ...`) to get a stack trace.  If others are successful in reproducing the problem you see, then one of us can file an issue.

Comment: Does indeed work now. I messed up on interpreting Map in the VSCode info as i imported it as ImmutableMap in File A and created a Type that was used in FIle B, where VSCOde called it map, plus methods on this Map didn't return what i did expect, but that was because reading immutable.js Docs 4 rc 9 Docs for immuable.js 3.8 in my App ...

Answer (score 1):

I have use immutable version 3.8.2 and it 's woring correcly with typescript.

```
import {Map} from 'immutable';

const map1 = Map( {a: 1, b: 4, c: 3 })
const map2 = map1.set('b', 2)
```

[**stackblitz typescript demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-immutable-map)

Import map function like this `import {Map} from 'immutable';` will conflict with javascript ES2015 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) so you cant use both of theme to solve this you can use another variable or alias to hold immutable map function like this

```
import {Map as _map} from 'immutable';

const map1 = _map( {a: 1, b: 4, c: 3 })
const map2 = map1.set('b', 2)
```

you can import entire immutable module mean all immutable function like this

```
import * as immutable from 'immutable';

const map1 = immutable.Map( {a: 1, b: 4, c: 3 })
const map2 = map1.set('b', 2)
```